# Input type time field does not work in all browsers

Tags: html, mozilla

I need to integrate `from time` and `to time` input field in my webpage. For that I used `input type=time` field but it's not working in all browsers like Mozilla.

From

```
 <input type="time" name="time" />
```

To

```
 <input type="time" name="time1" />
```

Comment: I do not understand this question, but perhaps it is referring to a specific version of Firefox that would now work. Voting to close as "Lacks Clarity" presently.

Answer (score 0):

This type of HTML5 input is not working in Firefox but in Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE it works.

You have 2 solutions:
1. Put a placeholder with the format that this input require for the Firefox users. If you put a placeholder, it only appears in Firefox and Firefox users may write manually the time but the users that use other browser can use this input correctly.

2. You can implement a timepicker yourself or use one that has already been create. Here you can find a timepicker library if you would try to implement yourself: http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timepicker/

I hope that this helps you with this issue.